# airflow defferable operator no triggering

Tags: airflow

Trying to implement a simple deferrable operator based on this [example](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/deferring.html), nothing seems to appear after the manual triggering of my DAG (same case with the exact code of example).

```
class TestDefer(BaseOperator):
    def execute(self, context):
        print("--- execute --")

        self.defer(
            trigger=TimeDeltaTrigger(delta=timedelta(seconds=1)),
            method_name="func",
        )

    def func(self, context, event=None):
        print("--- func ----")
        pass

with DAG(
    "def_dag", schedule_interval=None, start_date=datetime.now(),
) as dag:
    t = TestDefer(task_id="defer_task")
```

and then :
*airflow dags test  def_dag now*
*airflow triggerer*

Result : *func* is never called.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your deferrable operator code is correct. I tested it with the DAG below in Airflow 2.5.1 (only changed the print statements to logs and the start_date because `datetime.now()` can lead to issues when scheduling, but it should work manually as you had it).

Is the issue the same when you run the DAG manually from the UI? Using `airflow dags test...` I get an output without `"--- func ----"` but manually running the DAG from the UI the line prints and the DAG works as expected. (might be loosely related to [this issue](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/28865)).

If manually running from the UI does not work: what is the output of `docker ps`?

```py
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from airflow.triggers.temporal import TimeDeltaTrigger
from airflow.models.baseoperator import BaseOperator

import logging

# get Airflow logger
log = logging.getLogger('airflow.task')

class TestDefer(BaseOperator):
    def execute(self, context):
        log.info("--- execute --")

        self.defer(
            trigger=TimeDeltaTrigger(delta=timedelta(seconds=1)),
            method_name="func",
        )

    def func(self, context, event=None):
        log.info("--- func ----")
        pass

with DAG(
    "def_dag",
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1),
    catchup=False
) as dag:

    t = TestDefer(task_id="defer_task")
```

Answer (score 0):

After few tests, with Airflow 2.5.1, and your advices, my deferrable operator works following these steps :

- launching of airflow scheduler
- launching of airflow triggerer
- `airflow dags test...` or from the UI

Thanks for the help.